# new signature of setstate method in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was going through the article below.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

I found before the setState look like below.

```
this.setState({mykey: 'my new value'});
```

But there is a new signature like below.

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {myInteger: prevState.myInteger + props.step};
});
```

The offical doc explains that **'This enqueues an atomic update that consults the previous value of state and props before setting any values.'.**
But I do not understand. I know there is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState. But will the new signature method be synchronous or have other effects?

Could someone explain it?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your state object is just `{ counter: 1 }` at the beginning, the difference between calling `setState` with an object and a function is the following:

Suppose you do

```
setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1});
setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1});
```

Given that setState is async, it may be the case (and this will happen if you try it now), that both of those objects passed to setState evaluate to `{ counter: 2 }` and so after the two calls, you'll have an unexpected `{ counter: 2 }` state object!

If you pass functions:

```
setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter + 1}))
setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter + 1}))
```

This will be enqueued in the order their setState calls were invoked, and given that the object inside the function is dynamically calculated, you'll end up with the correct (or expected) answer of `{ counter: 3 }`.